# search filter in listview returns wrong value on item click

Tags: android, listview, android-filterable

I have a listview getting filtered by an edit text on top.However when i click on the item searched i get the result of another item being selected. there r also some data stored in my array which is not visible on listview , is also returning wrong data.
On searching C you get the result filtered as C.But clicking on it results is like the position does not change for the other data but uses the original ArrayList adapter position.

Any help will be appreciated.

My items:

```
public class Leave_master_items {
   public  String leave_id;
   public  String leave_Name;
   public  String is_hourly;
   public Leave_master_items(String leave_Name) {
        this.leave_Name = leave_Name;
    }

    public String getLeave_id() {
        return leave_id;
    }

    public void setLeave_id(String leave_id) {
        this.leave_id = leave_id;
    }

    public String getLeave_Name() {
        return leave_Name;
    }

    public void setLeave_Name(String leave_Name) {
        this.leave_Name = leave_Name;
    }

    public String getIs_hourly() {
        return is_hourly;
    }

    public void setIs_hourly(String is_hourly) {
        this.is_hourly = is_hourly;
    }

    }
```

My Adapter:

```
public class Leave_name_adapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    ArrayList<Leave_master_items> cm = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Leave_master_items> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
      //  return null;
    }

    static class ListViewHolder {
        TextView leaveType;
    }

    public Leave_name_adapter(ArrayList<Leave_master_items> cm, Context context) {
        this.cm = cm;
        this.context = context;
        mStringFilterList = cm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cm.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cm.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ListViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leaves_listview, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
            viewHolder.leaveType = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.leavestype);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Leave_master_items l = (Leave_master_items) getItem(position);
        viewHolder.leaveType.setText(l.getLeave_Name());
        return row;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
          //  cm.clear();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Leave_master_items> filterList = new ArrayList<Leave_master_items>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getLeave_Name().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {



                        Leave_master_items country = new Leave_master_items(mStringFilterList.get(i).getLeave_Name());

                        filterList.add(country);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            cm = (ArrayList<Leave_master_items>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

My activity:

```
leave_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Leave_list().execute();
            a.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.date_button_bg);
            date.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.leave_button_bg);
            leave_btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#293038"));
            date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F8F8F8"));


            search_leave.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Leave_application.this.leave_name_adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                              int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        }
    });

private class Leave_list extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        leave_master_itemses.clear();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        leave_name_adapter=new Leave_name_adapter(leave_master_itemses,getApplicationContext());
        listview_leave.setAdapter(leave_name_adapter);


        listview_leave.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Object a = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

                String b = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);



                Leave_master_items leave_master_items=leave_master_itemses.get(position);
                selectedFromList=leave_master_items.getLeave_id();
                Log.d("Yourtag", selectedFromList);


                // Log.d("Clicked item field", " "+ item.getColum(your colum index));
            }

        });



    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            Login_json_parser jParser = new Login_json_parser();

            String s = session.isWEBURL()+"?Function=" + session.isKEY_USERNAME() + "&Emp=" + session.iskey_emp_id();
            Log.d("s", s);

            JSONObject json1 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(s);

            Log.d("Inputfdfdtsale Stream", "json1");


                try {
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json1.toString()).nextValue();
                    Leave = object.getString("Leave");
                    Log.d("ew", Leave);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Leave);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                        jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Leave_master_items leave_master_items = new Leave_master_items(null);
                        leave_master_items.setIs_hourly(jsonObject.getString("is_hourly"));
                        leave_master_items.setLeave_id(jsonObject.getString("leave_id"));
                        leave_master_items.setLeave_Name(jsonObject.getString("leave_Name"));

                        leave_master_itemses.add(leave_master_items);

                    }

                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;

    }
    }
```

Comment: its because you are doing notifydatasetchanged() so the list is  changed

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask the adapter to get the right object.

Instead of

```
Leave_master_items leave_master_items = leave_master_itemses.get(position);
```

try

```
Leave_master_items leave_master_items = listview_leave.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

**UPDATE**

When you filter you don't have to create a new object with the same content. Just use the object which already exist.

Instead of

```
Leave_master_items country = new Leave_master_items(mStringFilterList.get(i).getLeave_Name());

filterList.add(country);
```

Do

```
filterList.add(mStringFilterList.get(i));
```

**UPDATE2**

Don't return 0 in `getItemId()`

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't shows get method after getadapter(). Is that any another way?

Comment: What's the exact problem after using my solution?

Comment: problem is still the same. after filtering it still shows old adpater position items.

Comment: I think i solved your problem. You always create a new object when you filter and the other information is lost. Just use the object which already exist. Updated my answer.

Comment: still the same problem. adapter is not updating

Comment: not working. after filtering when i click on listview item item it shows the old adapter settled positions

Comment: Mhh i think don't understand your current problem exactly. Can you please provide a test case in which you describe which values are in the list, with which chars you want to filter, which result you expect and which result you get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is as soon as you start searching something in edittext, your list content changes and you might be using the old list to get the item.

Create a setter in your adapter class for the list you just got after filtering and use that list in your onItemCLick to fetch the position you want to fetch.